# How can I make QT Creator stop logging warning exceptions?

Tags: c++, qt, suppress-warnings

I'm using QT Creator and the exception warnings really sucks, because they're logging everywhere.

Example in compiler output:
Exception at 0x7ffad5e54008, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) (first chance) at

At Issues:

[image: At Issues, the annoying warning]

How can I disable this behavior?

Comment: Rather than suppressing warnings/errors/exceptions you should investigate and *fix* their root cause.

Comment: The app can throw exceptions, catch it and go on as expected behavior. I don't want warnings in these cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows: Go to Tools -> Options -> CDB -> Add Exceptions to Issues View -> uncheck "First chance exceptions".

Contrary to what I expected it does two things: remove the exceptions from the issues view, and stop them from appearing in the application output tab.

[image]